# accordion - one panel nested in some div

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

How I can nested one panel in div? 
Problem is when this panel nested in div is open then cannot close when I open other panel. I need this because I am going to hide few panel. The div which panels are nested I want to set on display: none.

```
<div class="panel-group" id="accordion1">
<div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
        <h4 class="panel-title">
            <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion1" href="#collapseOne">
                Collapsible Group Item #1
            </a>
        </h4>
    </div>
    <div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse">
        <div class="panel-body">Panel 1</div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
        <h4 class="panel-title">
            <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion1" href="#collapseTwo">
                Collapsible Group Item #1
            </a>
        </h4>
    </div>
    <div id="collapseTwo" class="panel-collapse collapse">
        <div class="panel-body">Panel 2</div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="divWhichIWantHide">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">
            <h4 class="panel-title">
                <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion1" href="#collapseThree">
                    Collapsible Group Item #1
                </a>
            </h4>
        </div>
        <div id="collapseThree" class="panel-collapse collapse">
            <div class="panel-body">Panel 3</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

[SAMPLE](http://www.bootply.com/B6O8Qsnqfy)

Comment: So your sample is showing one panel, with several part (3). You need anothers panel in each parts is that right ?

Comment: maybe I wrong write. Open sample, and open first part where body is "Panel 3", and don't close it. Then open any other part and this is problem. Part with body "Panel 3" does not close, because is nested in div. Question is how I can make it to work correctly. I mean when I open part with body Panel 3 and next I open any other part then that one was closing automatically

Comment: If you can rid of your div that wrap the nested accordion part "Panel 3", you fix it. Is that a requirement to have this particular div ? (see example [here](http://www.bootply.com/AllFcvP0Af))

Comment: no, i must have this div. See this example [link](http://www.bootply.com/skwZ8AZm3o)
part Panel 3 default should be hidden, so I must have div

Answer (score 1):

When wrapping a div to another div, ask yourself : in what this particular div is special ? Can this div be avoided ?

In general, when you add a div to wrap another div, lets say this :

```
<div class="div1">
    <div class="div2"></div>
</div>
```

You can merge the "class" to themselves, like you must have seen with Bootstrap components :

```
<div class="div1 div2"></div>
```

Doing that, you just have to be sure properties of `div1` will not alter effect of css for class `div2`.

here is your fixed project : [**Editable Bootply sample**](http://www.bootply.com/OFjXlb8dhY)